# What is the effect of applying toeplitz matrix on both sides of + semi-def matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I have a positive semi-def matrix $\mathbf{A}$ that has an eigen value decomposition $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{V\Lambda V^T}$. I have a real toeplitz matrix $\mathbf{Q}$.

Can I say anything definite about the product $\mathbf{Q^TAQ}$? Under what conditions will $\mathbf{Q^TAQ}$ will also be positive semi-def?

Comment: For any positive semidefinite $A$ and any matrix $Q$, $Q^TAQ$ will be positive semidefinite.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Can you make a reference to its formal proof.

Comment: Note that $x^TQ^TAQx=(Qx)^T A (Qx)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $A$ is positive definite if and only if $x^TAx \geq 0$ for every vector $x$.

So, if $A$ is positive definite, we have
$$
x^T(Q^TAQ)x = (Qx)^TA(Qx)\geq 0
$$
which means $Q^TAQ$ is positive semidefinite.